# cURL giving error while sending data from localhost to live server

Tags: php, json, curl

sync.php is in localhost through which data is getting send to server to file sync1.php,
but while executing the sync.php which is on localhost its giving error only. the sync.php code is as follow:

```
include_once('db/connection.php');  
$len = $_REQUEST['key']; echo '<br>';
$sqlmob = "SELECT * FROM tblqeue limit 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlmob);
$res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$serialNo           = $res['serialNo'];    
$customerName       = $res['customerName']; 
$phoneNo            = $res['phoneNo'];
$mail               = $res['mail'];
$customerPincode    = $res['customerPincode'];
$customerCity       = $res['customerCity'];
$customerState      = $res['customerState'];
$warrantyStatus     = $res['warrantyStatus'];
$productDescription = $res['productDescription'];
$serviceType        = $res['serviceType'];
$typeOfRepair       = $res['typeOfRepair'];
$productFamily      = $res['productFamily'];
$serv_charges       = $res['serv_charges'];
$problemReported    = $res['problemReported'];
$techComment        = $res['techComment'];
$createdUser        = $res['createdUser'];
$location           = $res['location'];
$reloc              = $res['rloc'];

//curl starts

$data = array(array (
    'length'  => $len,
    'serialNo' => $serialNo,
    'customerName' => $customerName,
    'phoneNo' => $phoneNo,
    'mail' => $mail,
    'customerPincode' => $customerPincode,
    'customerCity' => $customerCity,
    'customerState' => $customerState,
    'warrantyStatus' => $warrantyStatus,
    'productDescription' => $productDescription,
    'serviceType' => $serviceType,
    'typeOfRepair' => $typeOfRepair,
    'productFamily' => $productFamily,
    'serv_charges' => $serv_charges,
    'problemReported' => $problemReported,
    'techComment' => $techComment,
    'createdUser' => $createdUser,
    'location' => $location,
    'rloc' => $reloc
    ));
//print_r($data);echo '<br>';echo '<br>';
// json encode data    
$data_string = json_encode($data); 
//print_r($data_string);
// set up the curl resource
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.testsite.com/sync1.php");   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                      
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
)); 

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
if ($output === false) {
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' .var_export($info));
} //every time its going to print the "error occured during curl exec.additional info
curl_close($ch);
$decoded = json_decode($output);
if (isset($decoded->response->status) && $decoded->response->status == 'ERROR') {
    die('error occured: ' . $decoded->response->errormessage);
}
var_export($decoded->response);
```

To receive the data on sync1.php I have coded like this but the data is coming, don't know why:

```
 $result_data       = json_decode($output, TRUE);
 $len               = $result_data['length'];
 $serialNo          = $result_data['serialNo'];
 $customerName      = $result_data['customerName'];
 $phoneNo           = $result_data['phoneNo'];
 $mail              = $result_data['mail'];
 $customerPincode   = $result_data['customerPincode'];
 $customerCity      = $result_data['customerCity'];
 $customerState     = $result_data['customerState'];
 $warrantyStatus    = $result_data['warrantyStatus'];
 $productDescription= $result_data['productDescription'];
 $serviceType       = $result_data['serviceType'];
 $typeOfRepair      = $result_data['typeOfRepair'];
 $productFamily     = $result_data['productFamily'];
 $serv_charges      = $result_data['serv_charges'];
 $problemReported   = $result_data['problemReported'];
 $techComment       = $result_data['techComment'];
 $createdUser       = $result_data['createdUser'];
 $location          = $result_data['location'];
 $reloc             = $result_data['rloc'];
```

How to send and receive the data, anyone can help?

Comment: explain what the error is please because `"its giving error only"` is not very descriptive

Comment: while executing sync.php which is sending data to sync1.php its giving error "error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: " ,$output === false that is why th above error is coming, why its giving $output false not getting exactly.

Comment: that is basically what you have in the code - what does the error output contain?

Comment: that much only so i am not getting data on sync1.php

Comment: why are there two `$output = curl_exec($ch);`? and is there nothing in `$info`?

Comment: use $data = $res I dont no why are you making the same array again

Comment: Arrayarray ( 'url' => 'https://www.t.com/sync1.php', 'content_type' => NULL, 'http_code' => 0, 'header_size' => 0, 'request_size' => 0, 'filetime' => -1, 'ssl_verify_result' => 1, 'redirect_count' => 0, 'total_time' => 1.183502, 'namelookup_time' => 0.98, 'connect_time' => 1.13, 'pretransfer_time' => 0, 'size_upload' => 0, 'size_download' => 0, 'speed_download' => 0, 'speed_upload' => 0, 'download_content_length' => -1, 'upload_content_length' => -1, 'starttransfer_time' => 0, 'redirect_time' => 0, '

Comment: i have removed that one by mistake i have added two $output = curl_exec($ch);

Answer (score 0):

The error output ( `$info` ) shows lots of zeros where you would normally not expect to see them, most notably the `http_code`. Presumably the remote script does send data back but that is not detailed in the quesion so I assume that is ok.

Working with `https` and `curl` in the past I have always found that using some of the many options available for ssl have helped. I am curious why the data has to be json_encoded but I hope the following helps in some way

```
<?php

    include_once('db/connection.php');

    $len = $_REQUEST['key'];

    $sqlmob = "SELECT * FROM tblqeue limit 1";
    $result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sqlmob );
    $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result );

    if( $res ){

        /* '$res' is already an array */
        $data=$res;
        $data['length']=$len;


        $data_string = json_encode( $data );
        /* download from curl.haxx.se and change path to suit */
        $cacert='c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem';

        $url='https://www.testsite.com/sync1.php';



        $ch = curl_init();

        /* set some ssl specific options */
        if( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_SCHEME )=='https' ){
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, realpath( $cacert ) );
        }

        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );   
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen( $data_string )
        )); 



        $output = curl_exec( $ch );
        $info = curl_getinfo( $ch );
        curl_close( $ch );

        if ( $info['http_code']!=200 && $output === false ) {
            die( 'error occurred during curl exec. Additional info: ' .var_export( $info ) );
        }


        $decoded = json_decode( $output );


        if ( isset( $decoded->response->status ) && $decoded->response->status == 'ERROR' ) {
            die( 'error occurred: ' . $decoded->response->errormessage );
        }
        var_export( $decoded->response );
    }
?>
```